# Left join and where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause

Here i come with the problem to join the table so i tried with the left join and where condition but am not getting a excepted result.i am newbie to mysql so could some one help on this

query:

```
SELECT 
m.mon, 
m.monthnames,
d.Outlet_Name, 
e.category_Name, 
f.Department_Name,
b.Item_Name, 
SUM(a.Item_Qty) AS Qty, 
SUM(a.Net_amount+a.Item_tax1) AS NetAmount 
 FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS mon, 'Jan' AS monthnames
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 'Feb'
    UNION
    SELECT 3, 'Mar'
    UNION   
    SELECT 4, 'Apr'
    UNION
    SELECT 5, 'May'
    UNION
    SELECT 6, 'jun'
    UNION
    SELECT 7, 'july'
    UNION
    SELECT 8, 'Aug'
    UNION
    SELECT 9, 'Sep'
    UNION
    SELECT 10, 'Oct'
    UNION
    SELECT 11, 'NoV'
    UNION
    SELECT 12, 'Dec'
       ) AS monthno
  LEFT JOIN KOT_Items a 
  ON MONTH(a.tran_date) = m.mon
   Item_Master b,
        KOT_Main c,
        Outlet d,
        Category_Master e,
        Department_Master f,
  WHERE a.Main_Item_Code=b.Item_Code
  AND e.Category_Code=b.Category_Code
  AND e.Category_Code =f.Category_Code
  AND d.Outlet_id = c.outlet_id
  AND a.ref_no=c.ref_no
  GROUP BY 
   m.mon, 
   m.monthnames, 
   d.Outlet_Name,
   e.category_Name, 
   f.Department_Name, 
   b.Item_Name
```

Excepted Result to be like this:

```
mon monthnames Outlet_Name      netamount

4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS           1
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS           100
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS           150
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS           1500
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS  
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS  
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS      
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS  
4   Apr MEXICAN AMIGOS  
1   jan
2   feb
3   mar
5   may
6   june
7   july
8   Aug
9   Sep
10  Oct
11  nov
12  Dec
```

Comment: change every inner join to left join

Comment: if its possible  update my query its useful to learn from u??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your table structure or your requirements . 
I have shown you the syntax  if that is  what you are looking for.

```
SELECT
m.mon,
m.monthnames,
d.Outlet_Name, 
e.category_Name, 
f.Department_Name,
b.Item_Name, 
SUM(a.Item_Qty) AS Qty, 
SUM(a.Net_amount+a.Item_tax1) AS NetAmount 
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS mon, 'Jan' AS monthnames
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 'Feb'
    UNION
    SELECT 3, 'Mar'
    UNION
    SELECT 4, 'Apr'
    UNION
    SELECT 5, 'May'
    UNION
    SELECT 6, 'jun'
    UNION
    SELECT 7, 'july'
    UNION
    SELECT 8, 'Aug'
    UNION
    SELECT 9, 'Sep'
    UNION
    SELECT 10, 'Oct'
    UNION
    SELECT 11, 'NoV'
    UNION
    SELECT 12, 'Dec'
       ) AS m
  LEFT JOIN KOT_Items a
  ON MONTH(a.tran_date) = m.mon
  LEFT JOIN  Item_Master b
  ON a.Main_Item_Code=b.Item_Code
  LEFT JOIN KOT_Main c
  ON a.ref_no=c.ref_no
  LEFT JOIN   Outlet d
  ON d.Outlet_id = c.outlet_id
  LEFT JOIN  Category_Master e
  ON e.Category_Code=b.Category_Code
  LEFT JOIN  Department_Master f
  ON e.Category_Code =f.Category_Code
  GROUP BY
   m.mon,
   m.monthnames,
   d.Outlet_Name,
   e.category_Name,
   f.Department_Name,
   b.Item_Name
```